# Terraform/GCP: ssh-keys not being added to metdata

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm trying to add ssh-keys to my Google Cloud project at the project level with terraform:

```
resource "google_compute_project_metadata_item" "oslogin" {
  project = "${google_project_services.myproject.project}"
  key     = "enable-oslogin"
  value   = "false"
}

resource "google_compute_project_metadata_item" "block-project-ssh-keys" {
  project = "${google_project_services.myproject.project}"
  key     = "block-project-ssh-keys"
  value   = "false"
}

resource "google_compute_project_metadata_item" "ssh-keys" {
  key   = "ssh-keys"
  value = "user:ssh-rsa myverylongpublickeythatireplacewithtexthereforobviousreasons user@computer.local"

  depends_on = [
    "google_project_services.myproject",
  ]
}
```

I tried all types of combinations of the 2 metadata flags oslogin and block-project-ssh-keys, which always get set without issues. But the ssh keys never appear in GCPs web GUI let alone the authorized_keys file. I even tried adding the depends_on, to make sure the project is existent before adding the keys, but that didn't help either.

Yet, Terraform says:

```
google_compute_project_metadata_item.ssh-keys: Creation complete after 8s (ID: ssh-keys)
```

Adding the exact same key manually on the web GUI works fine. At this point I believe I have tried everything, read all the first page Google results to 'terraform gcp add ssh key' and similar queries ... I'm at my wits end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the ssh key was being added to a different project. 
I started with Google's [tutorial on GCP/Terraform](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/managing-gcp-projects-with-terraform). This creates a generic project with the *gcloud* tool first. Then proceeds to create accounts using that generic project. This is necessary because you need a user to run terraform against their API. Then they create a *new* project facilitating these users with terraform each time you *apply*. The generic project created with gcloud is not being touched after the initial creation. 
If you omit the "project" parameter from the *google_compute_project_metadata_item.ssh-keys* resource, it used the generic project and added the ssh keys there - at least in my case.

**Solution:** explicitly add the *project* parameter to the metadata resource item to make sure it's being added to the right project

Comment: "explicitly add the project parameter to the metadata resource item to make sure it's being added to the right project"

This is what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @Mia please see the code snippet in my original post. Unlike in the first 2 blocks, the "project" parameter is missing from the ssh-keys block. Just add it there as well.